How to create a galvanized pipe with a twist?
How to create a twisted pipe like in the picture below? I've tried using curves, bezier, point and circle but no luck. Perhaps I am just doing it incorrectly.


Add an Archemedian Curve spiral and edit its parameters.


Extrude on Y and change Mean Radius of 4 vertices.

Add some Bevel Depth.

Add and edit another spiral.

Copy on the other side, right click > Convert to Mesh, add materials and lights.


Thank you so much to josh sanfelici for taking the time to provide this helpful answer! Really appreciate this community!
